# Component not rendering on redirecting to same page

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, render

I am working on a react app. So I have these components in my homepage

1. Sidebar
2. Sidebar Suggestions
3. Tags
4. Tags Suggestions

My Main Routing is like :

```
<Router>
    <Route path={["/", "/home", "/tags/:tagId"]} component ={Home}/>
</Router>
```

And my Home component is :

```
<Sidebar {some Props} />

  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
         exact
         path={["/", "/home"]}
         render={(props) => (
           <Suggestions {some props} />
         )}
      />
      <Route exact path="/tags/:tagId" component={TagsSuggestion} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>

<Tags { some props}  />
```

So whenever I click on any data in Sidebar, I want Sidebar Suggestions to render

And Whenever I click on any tag in tags component, It will redirect to " /tags/:tagId " with the tag Id attached.

Problem :
In the starting, the Sidebar suggestions are being shown ( which i want ), but whenever I click on tags, the Sidebar Suggestions component is not removed but the URL changes. And I have to reload the page manually to see the Tags Suggestions component.

Link for sandbox version :  https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-wave-v9m3r?file=/src/Tags.js

Comment: Can you try reproducing this issue into a *running* codesandbox that can be live debugged?

Comment: I added that just now. You can check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the `history.push` to function as expected, it *should* be placed *within* the `Router` component. Just move `Tags` component into the `Router` so it has a router context to use.

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <Sidebar />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/tags/:id" component={TagsSuggestion} />
            <Route path="/" component={SidebarSuggestion} />
          </Switch>
          <Tags />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit component-not-rendering-on-redirecting-to-same-page]

Comment: Wow, it was so simple